# Azure Data Factory V2 Trigger Pipeline only when current execution finished

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way I can create a trigger in Azure Data Factory that will only kick my pipeline if it's not already running? I basically want to run a pipeline continuously and so for whatever reason it finished (failure / success) I want it to resume as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi @Adn maybe you can have in your data factory flow azure function or logic app that will run a new instance of your pipeline when it's finished. 
So, on every failure, you will start a new instance and also at the end of the pipeline, you will have that logic app (or azure function) that will create and run a new instance of your pipeline. 

This is something that came to my mind

Answer (score 5):

You could try creating a scheduled trigger with a recurrence of 1 minute (this is the minimum possible interval for a schedule trigger) and you can set pipeline Concurrency to 1. What this does is it will start the first run, then the trigger runs again and tries to run the pipeline, but since the first run hasn't finished, it will add it to the queue. After the first run finishes, it will start to run the second one.

[image]

[image]

Please note that there is a limit on Queue size of 100, so when using pipeline concurrency of 1 could have 1 pipeline run 'InProgress' and 100 in the 'Queue', after that, if they keep triggering they will get error 429.

Comment: is there way to not even add it in a queue? just ignore the next trigger if there is one currently in-progress.

Comment: I would also like to know if there is a way to prevent it from ending up in the queue.